# Connecting PLC with sinking output to PWM analog converter

Tags: pwm, plc

I am using this [pwm converter](http://www.icstation.com/voltage-converter-module-adjustable-converter-power-module-digital-analog-signal-p-12498.html) with this [PLC](http://velocio.net/). The PLC digital out is sinking transistor type.

[image: PLC Digital Out]

I changed the pwm converter jumper switch to 24V and connected +24VDc from PSU to PWM terminal and one of the PLC's digital out to GND of the PWM port. Then I measured the analog out when the pwm input is 0% and it keep showing 10V while it is supposed to be 0V. Does anybody know where did I do wrong and how to correct it?

My current wiring:

[image: Connection Diagram]

Comment: it is unclear what you did ... it reads like this `i connected PWM input to 24 V and i shorted the PLC output to ground` ... think about it, you severed the connection between the PLC and the PWM converter and you tied the converter input high

Comment: this may help ... google `open collector outputs`

Comment: I have updated the post with wiring picture. Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: The pwm module instruction said: "Connect PWM Positive to PWM and Negative to Gnd".

Answer (score 1):

`<lecture>`First problem: You've linked to an Amazon advert and not a datasheet. Generally our advice is, "No datasheet? No sale!" Other sales outlets are more expensive because they provide documentation and that costs them money to produce and maintain. `</lecture>`

Second problem:

```
Hardware Interface:
VCC     DC 12V-30V
GND     Ground
PWM     Positive of PWM input signal    <--- Important
GND     Negative of input signal        <--- Even more important
VOUT    Output Voltage 0-10V
GND     Output Voltage Ground
```

The device requires a positive switching signal. Your PLC is switching the output to the negative rail.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYlp62.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Here SW1, 2 and 3 represent the PLC output transistor.*

Figure 1c may solve your problem. R1 pulls up the PWM input when the transistor output is off. Since the logic has now been inverted then your PWM modulation will have to be inverted also. This means that when you want, say, 25% analog out that you will give 100% - 25%  = 75% PWM. That should be easy to achieve in the PLC logic.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to implement a relay to your solution. Your PLC's sinking type, so your output works as a ground/negative and doesn't provide power. It simply completes the circuit.